# 1mysql xdevapi c++ fetching datetime value

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

using the Mysql XDev API C++, fetching a date time value as so -

```
    try {
        session.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `horizon`.`test` ( \
            `idtest` INT NOT NULL, \
            `testint` INT NOT NULL, \
            `teststring` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, \
            `testbool` TINYINT NOT NULL, \
            `testdate` DATE NOT NULL, \
            `testdatetime` DATETIME NOT NULL, \
            PRIMARY KEY(`idtest`)); \
        ").execute();

        std::cout << "Created Table `horizon`.`test`..." << std::endl;

        session.sql("INSERT INTO `horizon`.`test` (`idtest`, `testint`, `teststring`, `testbool`, `testdate`, `testdatetime`) VALUES (1, 100, \"test string\", true, \"1990-10-01\", \"1990-11-01 01:01:01\");").execute();

        std::cout << "Inserted 1 column into `horizon`.`test`..." << std::endl;
    }
    catch (mysqlx::Error& error) {
        std::cout << "error:" << error.what() << std::endl;
    }

    try {
        std::cout << "Fetching 1 column from `horizon`.`test`..." << std::endl;
        mysqlx::RowResult res = session.sql("SELECT * FROM `horizon`.`test` WHERE `idtest` = 1").execute();

        mysqlx::Row row = res.fetchOne();

        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(row[0].get<int>(), 1);
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(row[1].get<int>(), 100);
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(row[2].get<std::string>().compare("test string"), 0);
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(row[3].get<bool>(), true);
        // NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE BELOW
        std::cout << row[4].get<std::time_t>() << std::endl;
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(row[4].get<std::time_t>(), 0);
        std::cout << row[5].get<std::time_t>() << std::endl;
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(row[5].get<std::time_t>(), 0);

        std::cout << "Dropping table `horizon`.`test`..." << std::endl;
        session.sql("DROP TABLE `horizon`.`test`;").execute();
    }
    catch (mysqlx::Error& error) {
        std::cout << "error:" << error.what() << std::endl;
    }
```

What should rows 4 and 5 be fetched as? I'm getting an error fetching as time_t or int stating - `error:Can not convert to integer value`
getting the following when fetching as string -

```
☺
C:/Users/Sagun Khosla/Desktop/Repos/horizon/src/Tests/MySQLTest.cpp(98): error: in "MySQLTest": check row[4].get<std::string>().compare("1990-10-01") == 0 has failed [1 != 0]
╞
☺☺☺☺
C:/Users/Sagun Khosla/Desktop/Repos/horizon/src/Tests/MySQLTest.cpp(100): error: in "MySQLTest": check row[5].get<std::string>().compare("1990-11-01 01:01:01") == 0 has failed [1 != 0]
Dropping table `horizon`.`test`...
```

funny simleys :P